# 'module' object has no attribute 'CreateStructuringElementEx'

Tags: opencv, opencv3.1

`es = cv.CreateStructuringElementEx(9,9, 4,4, cv.CV_SHAPE_ELLIPSE)`

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CreateStructuringElementEx'

Why? Where I could see the differences between the versions?

Comment: In the opencv documentation maybe? And for any recent version is cv2.something...

Comment: I have not found. Version is 3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenCV 3 you should use:

```
cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(9,9))
```

Have a look at [OpenCV Python tutorials on morphological operations](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html)